# Problems styling MaterialUI Accordion heading

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, accordion

https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwindcss-react-boilerplat-forked-7yrez?file=/src/components/app.js

im having problems with the styling in my Accordion Heading.

I set my Accordion Contents like this:

```
<Accordion 
  heading1= { <DishItem name="Döner Teller Spezial" price="13,60€"/> }
  content1= { <AccordionContent /> }
</Accordion>
```

However, the way my flex-row is styled within my DishItem component (working without issues on other places, or tested by itself on tailwindplay.com) seems to break within the Accordion Heading and im not sure how to fix it.

This is my DishItem Component:

```
<div className="w-full"> 
    <div className="flex flex-row py-2 bg-white">
         <div>  
            <p className="pl-2 leading-none font-lato">{props.name}</p>
            <p className="pl-2 text-base leading-none"> { props.zusatz }
          </div>
          <p className="m-2 ml-auto place-self-center"> 24,50€</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This way of pushing the last flex element to the end of the container worked fine, but not within the heading. I am new to using materialUI and would appreciate any help to fix this.

Comment: can you create a codesandbox duplicating the issue?

Comment: I did here

https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwindcss-react-boilerplat-forked-7yrez?file=/src/components/app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem mostly comes from:

```
<AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
   <Typography className={classes.heading}>{props.heading1}</Typography>
</AccordionSummary>
```

Typography adds a `<P>` tag to your content and that's making it impossible for you to stretch the content.  You could also make your life much easier by using the `<Grid>` component from Material-UI.

See my sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwindcss-react-boilerplat-forked-5yv3w?file=/src/components/Accordion.js

Comment: Thank you so much! Was my first tiem using this component or MaterialUI in general so I didnt know this detail.